# mopabootstrap bundle bootstrap symbolic link error Permission denied on Windows

Tags: windows, symlink, permission-denied

On Windows, when you decided to let composer install Twitter's bootstrap, you might want to activate auto symlinking and checking, after composer update/install. And you get this error

Checking SymlinkScript Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

" [ErrorException]
 unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapBundle\Resources\public\bootstrap): Permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

This is because C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\mopa\bootstrap-bundle\Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Resources\public\bootstrap folder is now became a link and a folder which is confused with Windows. to fix this `you need to rename the bootstrap folder to something like bootstrap-link-source` and create a symlink with command like so

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\mopa\bootstrap-bundle\Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Resources\public>mklink bootstrap C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\vendor\mopa\bootstrap-bundle\Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Resources\public\bootstrap-link-source
```

i hopes it helps (tested).